# Tell Teseract to replace a character recognized by other one

Tags: tesseract

i'm doing ocr of a bunch of old newspaper. Tesseract is doing a really good, but there's only one problem:

is detecting almost (99%) "o" characters as "º".

If a make a whitelist character list excluding the "º" Tesseract doesn't replace with the most identical one (maybe the "o"), instead of that it only reject the recognition. So the word "Hola" become recognized has "Hla".

So do you know a configuration string to replace all "º" with "o" character?

I can do to the txt output simply with sed, but i need it for a PDF output.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `unicharambigs` file embedded in `.traineddata` file for Tesseract 3.03–3.05.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/Training-Tesseract-3.03%E2%80%933.05.md#the-unicharambigs-file

Comment: Thanks but i'm working with tesseract 4. Also i resolved the problem by using a best trainedata file for my language (spa).